# Can Apache cordova app send query to MS access database?

Tags: sql, cordova, ms-access, database-connection, connection-string

I have a local Microsoft Access database stored in a desktop PC which is connected in a LAN. I have also an apache cordova app which is connected to the same LAN.

So what I would to know is:

Is there a way to let the apache cordova app send a query to the Access database (which I remember is stored in the desktop PC)?

Comment: show what you have done here.

Comment: You will probably want to do this using some sort of api, that will fetch and execute the data for you.  See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming for an introduction to restful api development.